# Using Django Count() with conditional lookup types

Tags: mysql, sql, django, python-2.7, django-models

So I'm trying to aggregate exam data, and because the database lives on another server I'm trying to reduce this to as few database calls as possible.

I have this model (whose corresponding table is in a mySQL database if that matters):

```
class Exam(models.Model):
    submitted              = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    score                  = models.DecimalField(default=Decimal(0))
```

And this query:

```
>>> exam_models.Exam.objects\
...     .using("exam_datebase")\
...     .aggregate(average=Avg("score"),
...                total=Count("submitted"))
{'average': 22.251082, 'total': 231}
```

What I'm looking for is a way to also retrieve the number of passed exams, something along the lines of:

```
>>> exam_models.Exam.objects\
...     .using("exam_datebase")\
...     .aggregate(average=Avg("score"),
...                total=Count("submitted"))
...                passed=Count("score__gte=80"))
{'average': 22.251082, 'total': 231, 'passed': 42}
```

I know I can just send another query using `.filter(score__gte=80).count()`, but I was really hoping to get both the total count and the passing count on the same aggregate. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are either going to need two queries, or do the aggregation manually.

To see why, let's consider the underlying SQL that Django generates and uses to query the database.

```
Exam.objects.aggregate(average=Avg("score"), total=Count("submitted"))
```

roughly translates to

```
SELECT AVG(score), COUNT(submitted)
FROM exam
```

The "Count" part of the aggregate is applying to the SELECT clause in the underlying sql query.  But if we want to include only scores greater than some value, the SQL query would need to look something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(score), COUNT(submitted)
FROM exam
WHERE score > 80
```

Filtering Exams with a particular "score" is applies to the WHERE or HAVING clause of the underlying SQL statement.

Unfortunately, there is not really a way to combine these two things. So, you are stuck doing two queries.

Having said all that, if you REALLY want to do a single query, one option is to just do the aggregation in your python code:

```
exams = Exam.objects.all()
total_score = 0
total_submitted = 0
passed = 0
for exam in exams:
    total_score += exam.score
    if exam.submitted:
        total_submitted += 1
    if exam.score >= 80:
        passed += 1
exam_aggregates = {
    'average': total_score / len(exams),
    'submitted': total_submitted,
    'passed': passed,
}
```

Comment: This is a very helpful explanation. I figured I was out of luck when I was writing this post, but I really didn't understand why. Django's syntax is a bit confusing in that Count() uses the same <field>__<lookup type> syntax as filter() but then only supports some of the lookup types.

Comment: You should really add a disclaimer that python aggregation is a terrible idea! My reason for wanting to limit queries is that the database is on a different server.

If I use two queries I'm transmitting almost nothing over the network. They each return a few Decimal objects after running a mysql script on the other server.

If I use one query and pull the entire table then I'm transferring huge amounts of data over the network! I'm also taxing the web server by forcing a large queryset into memory as opposed to storing 3 Decimal values!